# SFML for Python in Windows 10

Tags: sfml

Could someone please tell me, how to install (step by step) SFML library for Python in Windows 10?
Please...
Thank You very much for any help. :)

I can't get to the SFML related material for Python and Win10.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python package installer, pip, to get the python bindings for sfml ([PySFML](https://github.com/intjelic/python-sfml))

```
pip install pySFML
```